# prepare for segue from collectionviewcell not displaing indexed item

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to segue to another viewcontroller from a collectionViewController and I also trying to get the index and pass data appropriately but when ever I select a cell, the detailVC just shows but nothing gets printed or anything of sorts

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == DETAIL_VC {

            print("ITEM SELECTED ")
            let vc = segue.destination as! DetailVC
            guard let selectedIndexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }
            let flickerPhoto = ServiceProvider.instance.flickerPhotos[selectedIndexPath.item]

            print("ITEM SELECTED ")
            vc.titleLabel.text = flickerPhoto.title
        }
}
```

nothing gets printed

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let flickerPhoto = ServiceProvider.instance.flickerPhotos[indexPath.item]
        let destinationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DETAIL_VC) as! DetailVC
        destinationVC.titleLabel.text = flickerPhoto.title

    }
```

i got the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the segue named `DETAIL_VC` from the yellow icon of the  source vc ( not from the cell ) to the destination , and use this inside `didSelectItemAt`

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:DETAIL_VC,sender:indexPath)
```

---

it crashes as you access an outlet that is nil before the vc is loaded , you can try to send the data as a String and set it inside `viewDidLoad` of the destination vc

```
destinationVC.titleValue = flickerPhoto.title
```

---

```
class DetailVC:UIViewController {

    var titleValue:String = ""

   // set it to the label text in `viewDidLoad`

    override func viewDidLoad() {

      super.viewDidLoad()

        self.titleLabel.text = titleValue
     }
}
```

Comment: using `didSelectItemAt` crashes the application

Comment: it does not crash again. Thanks but the label is not set.

Comment: it's strange how **loadViewIfNeeded** didn't work with you anway try the other way ?

Comment: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let flickerPhoto = ServiceProvider.instance.flickerPhotos[indexPath.item]
        let destinationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DETAIL_VC) as! DetailVC
        destinationVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
        destinationVC.titleValue = "\(flickerPhoto.title)"
        print("ITEM SELECTED \(String(describing: flickerPhoto.title))")
    }`

Comment: that is what my `didSelectItemAt` looks like now and it still does not work

Comment: remove this **destinationVC.loadViewIfNeeded()** and do last edit in answer

Comment: I fixed it by setting a selectedItem variable in my ServiceProvider class. it works fine now

Comment: hi kindly help check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360597/pagination-with-collectionview-working-with-api